# Why does the exported obj look wrong?

Tags: export, file-format, obj

I have created a model in blender in which I wish to use in my openGL application.  Before exporting I expected the obj file to look something similar to this.

[image]

However when I exported the file I got something like this

[image]

I started to ponder on whether I had exported it wrong or not, as this is the first time I have used blender.  I am currently using blender version 2.70.

Thanks

Comment: gandalf, I think you put the screenshots backwards

Comment: @Justin Whoops, good catch. thanks :) (no wonder I was so confused after editing it..)

Comment: Looks like you somehow managed to strip all newlines? Maybe Unix line endings on Windows system.

Comment: @ideasman42 is there anyway to solve this problem, or will I just have to read it into my application as is?

Comment: OBJ files export here with line endings, so its not clear what the problem is?

Comment: @DorkMonstuh If you open up the file in Notepad++, it should look like the Wikipedia example you provided. It shouldn't really make a difference, though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is (as guessed by ideasman42) that Blender exports .obj-files always (at least I tested it on windows and Linux) with Linux [line endings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) (that means there are only LF and no CR characters).

If you use a better editor than the standard Notepad you can often see the file correct even on Windows (for example with [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/)). There should be no problems using this file as it is, because I think most Programs can work with both line ending types. If it doesn't work it's easy to convert the line endings (as well with something like Notepad++).